# New-azurermadserviceprincipal : quota exceeded error

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-powershell, service-principal

I am creating a new application registration in AD, and then creating Service principal. For my login I have only 5 applications registered. When I try to create a new one I get "quota exceeded error". But for another user in same subscription it allows to create many registrations.

Is there a way to list all service principals for a **specific user** and then clean them up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - install the AzureADPreview cmdlets from here: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureADPreview/2.0.0.129

Then run:

```
Get-AzureADDeletedApplication -All $true
```

And see if that finds anything you expect not to be there - those are "soft deleted" apps.

If so, you can use

```
Remove-AzureADMSDeletedDirectoryObject
```

To remove any you don't need.  If you don't own them, you shouldn't be able to remove them...  I *think* only items you own are hitting your quota so should be fine to remove any and they become "hard deleted" (gone forever).  So make sure you don't need anything before deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

You could use [`Get-​Azure​Rm​AD​Service​Principal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/get-azurermadserviceprincipal?view=azurermps-4.1.0) to list all your service principals.

Use [`Remove-​Azure​Rm​AD​Service​Principal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/get-azurermadserviceprincipal?view=azurermps-4.1.0) to delete your service principals.

You also could manage your service principals on Azure Portal.  `Azure Active Directory--App registrations>`
[image]

Update:

Please ensure your account have the permission to create service principals.[image]

More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal).

Comment: I tried both the methods. As of not I have only 2 registrations in the portal, new registration is failing with "quota exceeded" error. not sure whats wrong with it.

Comment: @PavanKumar What is your user kind? Administrator or user?

Comment: @PavanKumar You had better check your User setting. Please ensure `Users can register applications` is yes. I update my answer, you could check it.

Comment: I have this option set to Yes. And the user is not Global admin. still my question is I have deleted all the app registrations, so I have not reached the quota yet (I don't have active objects). Then why this error? Does this quota means number of active objects or number of transactions made to create objects?

Comment: @PavanKumar Based on my knowledge, there is no limit on service principals. You could check your administrator account. If the account also could not create it. You could create a ticket on Azure Portal. This is free. Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-service-limits-restrictions).

Comment: Actually there is a limit on these objects (AD registered applications) if user is not global admin user. Also when AD entries are deleted, it is soft-deleted. So count does not go down as we delete from portal or power-shell script. We need get these objects which are in recycle bin and delete them regularly; to do this we need global admin user account.